# Unable to generate random number Visual C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors game as my first 'project' so I need the computer to generate a random number from 1-3 to represent their turn.

I've been trying this code but I can't figure out why it's not working:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int pchand= rnd.Next(1, 4);
```

There's a red squiggly line below rnd that says :

```
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property FileName.Form1.rnd
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you include the code to Form1?

Comment: Did you place it inside of method? Or just in class body?

Comment: Here's an incredibly bad idea: `int pchand = new Random().Next(1, 4);`

Comment: Is it a console or windows forms application?

Comment: @Downvoters: While I agree a more complete sample would be useful, this is indeed a very good first attempt from a new user. It includes the relevant code, and includes the specific error message too - which is an important factor that even long-time users miss out. As it stands, the question has enough information to be answered so doesn't really deserve the downvotes (in my opinion)

Answer (score 10):

The problem will be because you are doing this at a class level, rather than a function level.

It is fine to declare you Random at class level, but creating `pchand` should be done within a function.

Something like:

```
public class Test
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    public static void Main()
    {
        int pchand = rnd.Next(1, 4); 
    }
}
```

The reason why your original attempt causes a compile time error is because the compiler does not guarantee  the order in which fields are initialized. So there is no guarantee that `rnd` will be set before you use it. Thus the compiler prevents you from doing it to avoid unexpected null reference errors during runtime.

---

**Note to OP**: Including a more extended sample of your code would have allowed for a more specific solution to your problem, but hopefully my example code is generic enough for you to understand what you need to do

Comment: +1 but please, explain why "creating pchand should be done within a function"

Comment: You are obviously dealing with a beginner. Let's try to help him understand **why**, not just **what** he should fix.

Comment: @Tarik: yeah... didn't I already agree to do that in my previous comment? Anyway, feel free to add any comments yourself as to why...

Comment: rnd could be declared in Main, making the variable more local. This is a better practice unless there is a reason to keep it static.

Comment: Sorry if I sound picky, but although you provided a solution, you did not yet explain what the error message was about.

Comment: I went for the static approach for Random to help avoid the OP getting the same number if they was to use it in a loop. Although without anymore information about the OP's requirements we can't really say either way. My approach also helps to demonstrate using class and local scopes together

Comment: I got it to work thank you very much guys! And you're right, I'm a beginner in making Windows Application Forms, just started 4 hours ago :b

Comment: @user2911044: Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you. That way you can improve your rep and get more out of SatckOverflow next time you need some assistance!